# Nomenclature of the Acronyms

Tags: cisco-catalyst

What does the 'FPS' in WS-C2960S-48FPS-L mean? I have tried to run a search online and have not fount concrete answers so i came here

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The first two letters, **FP**, indicate 740 Watts of available PoE power, as opposed to **LP** which indicates 370 Watts of PoE power. Note that the F versus L letter only applies to 48-port PoE switches, since 370 Watts is full power for a 24 port PoE switch, and there are no 740 Watt nor 185 Watt 24 port models. Models without PoE are indicated with a **T** after the number of ports.

The third letter, **S**, indicates 4 one gigabit SFP ports, as opposed to **D** which indicates 2 ten gigabit SFP+ ports or 2 one gigabit SFP ports.

[Here's Cisco's list of part numbers for the 2960 line.](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-2960-series-switches/product_data_sheet0900aecd80322c0c.html)